# React.createClass is deprecated error in npm package

Tags: reactjs

I am using Facebook Fixed Data Tables in a project but their code is throwing the React.createClass warning/error.  Is it possible to fix a 3rd party module in your codebase in React or will I need to modify the node_module directly to get rid of this error.

Here is the error:
Scrollbar: React.createClass is deprecated in:
/node_modules/fixed-data-table/internal/Scrollbar.react.js

Answer (score 0):

According to the last commit in the [project](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table) was made half year ago, I guess that Facebook now spent few effort on it. It means that I do not think opening an issue on it would help.

However, the project [lock React on 14 or 15](https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table/blob/master/package.json#L7-L8). In these versions `React.createElement` API still works like a charm so you don't have to worry except the annoying warning.